# Fitting a matrix inside a designated space

Tags: border, fit

I put a large matrix in the documents and the matrix went beyong the border. I'm wondering how we can resize it? Here is the codes for the matrix:

```
\[\mathcal{W}_{i,:,:}=
\begin{bmatrix}
    \mat{W_1}[i,1] & \mat{W_1}[i,2] & ...& \mat{W_1}[i,d_1] \\
   \mat{W_1}[i,2] & \mat{W_1}[i,d_1+1] & ...& \mat{W_1}[i,2d_1-1]\\
   ...&...&...&...\\
   \mat{W_1}[i,d_1] &  \mat{W_1}[i,d_1+1] & ... &\mat{W_1}[i,\cfrac{1+d_1}{2}*d_1]
\end{bmatrix},
\]
```

It went over the boarder as shown in the following picture:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You may have to shrink the `\arraycolsep` and change the way it is displayed:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\mat}{\mathbf}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{align*}
  &\mathcal{W}_{i,:,:}= \\
  &\setlength{\arraycolsep}{.4\arraycolsep}
  \begin{bmatrix}
     \mat{W_1}[i, 1]  &     \mat{W_1}[i, 2]   & \cdots &           \mat{W_1}[i, d_1]                 \\
     \mat{W_1}[i, 2]  & \mat{W_1}[i, d_1 + 1] & \cdots &        \mat{W_1}[i, 2d_1 - 1]               \\
          \cdots      &         \cdots        & \cdots &                \cdots                       \\
    \mat{W_1}[i, d_1] & \mat{W_1}[i, d_1 + 1] & \cdots & \mat{W_1}[i, \tfrac{1 + d_1}{2} \times d_1]
  \end{bmatrix},
\end{align*}
\lipsum*[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Beside `\arraycolsep` you may shrink also spaces around math operators and distance between **W** and its index:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\bfW}{\mathbf{W}_{\!1}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum*[1]
\[\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1.5pt}
\mathcal{W}_{i,:,:}=  
  \begin{bmatrix}
     \bfW[i, 1]  & \bfW[i, 2]       & \dotsm & \bfW[i, d_1]        \\
     \bfW[i, 2]  & \bfW[i, d_1{+}1] & \dotsm & \bfW[i, 2d_1{-}1]   \\
     \dotsm      &    \dotsm        & \dotsm & \dotsm                   \\
    \bfW[i, d_1] & \bfW[i, d_1{+}1] & \dotsm & \bfW[i, \frac{1{+}d_1}{2} {\times} d_1]
  \end{bmatrix}\!,
\]
    \lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]